# How can I create a customized vim [in my own pc] and could install it on every server that I use in future?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I like my own customized vim that I use, but every time I ssh to a server I have to reinstall those plugins and customizations.

Does anyone have an easy method to install my own customized vim on any other servers?

Comment: Well packages can be easily installed through Vim's [native package manager](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i-use-it). So long as you have a modern-ish Vim installation on your remote machines, just port over your local, customized `.vimrc` and it should apply easily enough. If you need something more involved, write a bash script.

Comment: Instead of reinstalling plugins and customizations you could edit the remote files with your local vim. `vim scp://user@server//path/to/document`. This opens the file in your local vim (it actually copies the file locally), and when you save, it sends the edited file back to the server for you. Unfortunately you don't get path/file completion as you would when working directly on the machine.

Comment: I found a way to scp from my laptop to server `.vimrc` file and `.vim` directory copy all plugins that I've installed with it, all at once.